# Expected winnings?

Tags: probability

A box contains 7 black blocks, numbered 1-7, and 7 yellow blocks, numbered 1-7. You randomly select two blocks, without replacement without regard to color. The absolute difference of the numbers on the two blocks selected is how much you win. What is my expected winnings?

I’m not sure of how to solve. I started drawing a tree diagram, which got lengthy very quickly. I’m not sure of where to start at all. If i used p= 8 x= 2 n=16, could I use binomial tables to determine the answer?

Comment: You have posted this question 3 times in the last day.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you get a $3$ on your first pick, the expected value of the absolute difference equals $\dfrac{2}{13}(2+1) + \dfrac{1}{13}\cdot0 + \dfrac{2}{13}\left(1+2+3+4\right)$. In general, if you get a $k$ on your first pick (which for every $k$ happens $\dfrac{2}{14}$ of the time), the expected value equals $\displaystyle \dfrac{2}{13} \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (k-i) + \frac{1}{13}\cdot|k-k| + \dfrac{2}{13} \sum_{i=k+1}^7 (i-k) = \dfrac{2}{13} \sum_{i=1}^7 |k-i|$. Can you now finish it by summing over $k$?